# Map and merge values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

1.**input** dataframe with random num values:

```
ID  num
a    2
a,b  3
b    1
c,e  4
```

I have another dataframe:

```
ID  name
a    a1
b    b5
c    c4
d    d1
e    e6
```

2.**Expected result** : I want to map the df1 with df2 on ID and stored as another column:

```
ID  num  ID_name
a    2    a1
a,b  3    a1,b5
b    1    b5
c,e  4    c4,e6
```

3.code i tried:

```
df1["ID_name"] = df1["ID"].map(df2)
df1
```

But the values are not getting mapped and showing NAN for most of the values

Comment: want you want is a "merge"

Comment: yes, merge as per ID column

Comment: so look up df.merge and try that

Comment: but it is not merging the 2 values in same row

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and groupby on the elements.

```
df["ID_name"] = (
    df["ID"]
    .str.split(",")
    .explode()
    .map(df2.set_index("ID")["name"])
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(",".join)
)

    ID  num ID_name
0    a    2      a1
1  a,b    3   a1,b5
2    b    1      b5
3  c,e    4   c4,e6
```

Comment: it is in float. 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @AnubhavNegi It might be that your original dataframe is different from what you posted in the question. Can you post your original df.

Comment: i have rechecked it, the data format and everything is same

Comment: i will try once by converting the values to string

Comment: @AnubhavNegi What you've in the question has no floats at all. where did the float come from in the error msg?

Comment: ----> 7     .agg(",".join) is where it is showing error

Comment: @AnubhavNegi The posted answer works fine on the dfs you've posted in the question. Can you post the df you're working on.

Comment: i got the error, it was take the idexes as a value, so it was throwing such an error.

Comment: @AnubhavNegi My code runs fine on the data you've provided. Check this link https://replit.com/@Ch3seR/TailedBeast1000#main.py

Comment: is there any alternative, as processing time is too much for thousands of data in the dataframe?

Comment: @Anubhav In general dealing with string in pandas is slow than other dtypes. Upon that `explode` is also slow. I'll post if I find a better alternative. :)